# My discord bot array is empty. jda doesn't get a message

Tags: java, discord-jda

```
public class MainBot{
    public static String prefix = "!";
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws LoginException {
        EnumSet<GatewayIntent> intents = EnumSet.of(
                  GatewayIntent.GUILD_MEMBERS,
                  GatewayIntent.GUILD_EMOJIS,
                  GatewayIntent.GUILD_VOICE_STATES,
                  GatewayIntent.GUILD_MESSAGES
                );
        
        JDA jda = JDABuilder.createDefault(":D", intents)
                            .addEventListeners(new HorseCarculator())
                            .build();
    }
    
}

import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.annotation.Nonnull;

import net.dv8tion.jda.api.events.message.guild.GuildMessageReceivedEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter;

public class HorseCarculator extends ListenerAdapter{
    
    public void onGuildMessageReceived(@Nonnull GuildMessageReceivedEvent event) {
        
        String[] args = event.getMessage().getContentRaw().split("");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(args));
```

If you send a message, the array is empty.
help me

Answer (score 0):

You didn't enable the [Message Content Intent](https://jda.wiki/using-jda/troubleshooting/#cannot-get-message-content-attempting-to-access-message-content-without-gatewayintent). You should also consider updating, JDA is currently on version `5.0.0-alpha.21`.